# How to create a newsletter sign up block in Drupal

Tags: drupal, newsletter, subscribe

What is the best way to create a e-news subscribe block in Drupal with the form to collect information such as first and last name, email address and interests? I have spent some time Googling how to do this but am running into only very outdated information. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Using Drupal 7.50 with CiviCRM 4.7.15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Drupal 7 I would use [Drupal Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) - together with the [Webform CiviCRM](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) integration module, since the Webform module let's you set the form to show within a block.

These are pure drupal webform settings. This is done under Adv Settings, which is on the Form settings tab ie at node/xx/webform/configure "Available as block: 
If enabled this webform will be available as a block."

There are then controls as to whether you show the whole node in the block or just the form, which probably isn't an issue in your case.

Then set the civicrm settings on the webform to collect the various fields you want and add them to the Group that is used for the newsletter.

Comment: This worked. I had to enable CiviCRM Webform Integration Module first.

Comment: Thanks - I tried to clarify this a bit more in the Answer